# Why do I get the error "the byte at index is not ASCII" when using AsciiString::from_ascii on a byte array?

Tags: rust, ascii

I am getting an error whilst running `ascii::AsciiString::from_ascii` on a byte array.

The error is `thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed: the byte at index 3 is not ASCII'`

The byte at position 3 is 137 which should be a `ë`. I also got the values of positions 2 and 4 just to be certain I wasn't getting anything wrong with the indexing and they all appeared to have suitable values.

`bytes[2] = 38  // &`
`bytes[3] = 137 // ë`
`bytes[4] = 56  // 8`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Reading the [documentation for this function](https://docs.rs/ascii/1.0.0/ascii/struct.AsciiString.html#method.from_ascii) I am not entirely sure why this won't work.

What am I doing wrong and why is this error being thrown?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: [ASCII — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 5):

ASCII ends at ordinal value 127; `ë` is not ASCII (nor is 137 the ordinal value of `ë` in either latin-1 or cp1252, which people often mistake for ASCII). The error is correctly informing you of this.